# How to attach jar file to source file in Eclipse in a general case?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jar

I'm beginner of Eclipse. I've imported 2 **jar files** in Eclipse :
`example.jar`
`example-source.jar`

How to attach jar file to source file in Eclipse in a general case ?

[image]

By the way, I didn't see the **Attach Java source** option by right-clicking on `example.jar`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the right click menu select 'Properties' and then look at the 'Java Source Attachment' page